# Overriding one class with another using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation with three links. What I want to do is to show one of three boxes paired on these links if a specific link is clicked. I have these `<li>` elements with data-nav set:

```
<li class="active" data-nav="1">Prerender</li><li data-nav="2">Prefetch</li><li data-nav="3">Preconnect</li>
```

I also have these three boxes, which should be visible only if paired `<li>` element is clicked

```
<div class="content-box box1">
        <h3 id="isPrerender"> Prerendered page: <span id='pagetitle'></span></h3>
      </div>

      <div class="content-box box2">
        <h3 id="isPrerender"> Page2: <span id='pagetitle'></span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I have in my .css file

```
.box1, .box2, .box3{display: none;}
        .expanded{display: block !important;}
```

This is where I set the expanded class on the box which is paired with the `<li>` element clicked:

```
for (var i = 0; i < menu_items.length; i++) {
  menu_items[i].onclick = function() {

  var navId = this.getAttribute('data-nav');
  document.getElementByClassName('box' + navId).classList.add('expanded');

    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `display: none` is still set even when I add the `expanded` class. If I look into console, the `display: block` rule is here but is erased. How to rewrite It?

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName` is not a function. It should be getElement**s**byClassName

Comment: that didn't fix it @chazsolo

Comment: well "Elements" returns an html Collection....

Comment: I hope that didn't fix it, otherwise I'd be answering in a comment! :) Just pointing out a syntax issue that hopefully should point you in the right direction of _why_ it isn't working. As epascarello said, it's a collection... so you can't just call `classList` directly on it. (and when this is done right, you won't need !important. I'd recommend dropping that now)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can  set display none in first load with JavaScript or  (hide element)  then in function set display block or  (show the element)
And don't use !important for the class if you want to replace or you should remove class then add other class